# Device specific crash

Tags: android

I am getting a crash from my app on a very peculiar line of code that seems to have nothing wrong with it… In fact, this works on most devices, but not my nexus 7 (which is the only tablet I have tested it on, come to think about it).

here is the line of code it is breaking on,

```
findViewById(R.id.btbutton).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

which is inside `onResume`

and here is the stack trace

```
12-11 18:06:52.955    5674-5674/com.blank.blank E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blank.blank, PID: 5674
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.blank.blank/com.blank.blank.activities.MerchantListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at 

    com.blank.blank.activities.MerchantListActivity.onResume(MerchantListActivity.java:164)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
                at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2764)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Again keep in mind that this works on other devices. I've tried creating a button variable for the line of code and setting the visibility on that, I've checked that I have correctly set the content layout and I've checked that my variable names in the xml match the names in my activity. If I comment the line out it happens to a similar line of code also inside of `onResume`

Thanks for your help

Just in case, here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/merchant_list"
        android:name="com.blank.blank.fragments.MerchantListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="ly.wise.ProgramList"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/statuscalcbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculating Status"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_wisely"
        android:textColor="@color/white_opaque"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/calcexplain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="We'll notify you when we're done"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white_opaque"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Turn On Bluetooth"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white_opaque"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btbuttonexplain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tap to learn why"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white_opaque"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is where I set the layout in the oncreate method of my activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_merchant_list);
```

Comment: Can we see the activity code? Do the other devices you are using have different Android versions?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure is this would help but I would try declaring the button as a button first and then set the visibility:

```
btbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btbutton);
btbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: [`setVisibility` is a method on View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).